# getting a meta of multiple users in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a plugin with stores user activity in the table `wp_usermeta` and under `meta_key`  `user_last_activity` and `meta_value` something like `a:12:{}`  where `12` is the user id.

So, If I was logged in as user with id: `12` my current page would run this code:

```
$user = get_user_id();
$activity = get_user_meta($userid, 'user_last_activity', true);

var_dump($activity);
```

so, that's pretty much it. Except, if I was logged as admin, I would like to see ALL activity by all users.

So, is there anyway to get all user meta? currently I am blindingly doing

```
foreach(range(1, 1000) as $value){
    $activity = get_user_meta($value, 'user_last_activity', true);
    var_dump($activity); 
}
```

I am offcourse assuming there are 1000 users, but you can see the limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [get_users() function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) to get all of the users on your site, and then loop through those to grab the user activity.

```
$users = get_users(); // get array of WP_User objects
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    $activity = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'user_last_activity', true );
    var_dump( $activity );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can you maybe check this questions too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42791718/disable-ssl-connection-in-wordpress ? thanks

Comment: This is considered a very bad coding practise, an SQL query in a loop... stay away from it!

Answer (score 6):

I would advise to do a single query for the user_meta instead of running `get_user_meta` within a foreach-loop.

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT user_id, meta_value as 'user_last_activity'
FROM $wpdb->usermeta
WHERE `meta_key` = 'user_last_activity' 
");

var_dump($results);
```